# What is a good choice for database table like Paradox table for windows or Linux?

Tags: .net, linux, database, delphi-prism

My software was built around BDE Engine and Paradox table for windows from while back and I am in the process of converting it for .NET. I am looking around for options to implement the database feature of my software for .NET.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There has never been a `Paradox for Linux` driver, AFAIK. You  might be able to find an ODBC driver that will work for .NET. Your best bet, if you're thinking of going cross-platform, is to switch to a real database like Firebird and use ADO.NET to access it from Mono or .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). It's simple, fast, supported, and very rigorously tested.

Comment: theglauber, thanks for your answer. I just implemented SQLite and I just need to in corporated into my DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Just as I thought. There is just too many ifs and buts when it comes to database implementation. As I learned, BDE has not been supported in a long time. However, we have been using it for the last 5 years. Right now they don't support FireBird either. It is discontinued. Instead, they have now JayBird. It sounds like you need to have SDK JVM engine installed on your system if it is not installed already for it work.

I think, I am going to make use of the good old flat file. It will be simple. One of the main reason we would like to have true database table is to be able to search the table using SQL statements, which is what we do now through BDE engine.

Comment: Who is "they" who don't support Firebird? BDE is dead, and it won't run on Linux or OSX, and isn't supported for .NET apps either (except maybe through ODBC). If you've been using the  BDE for 5 years, you started using it 5 years after it was deprecated; it was dead when you began. You should replace it with something else, and that something else can  be Firebird, SQLite, or any of a dozen other XPlatform databases as long as you're doing the replacement anyway. A "good old flat file" is a bad idea if you have any volume of data at all or support more than one concurrent user.